# Passing Longitude and Latitude in Twitter Streaming API of Pakistan

Tags: c#, java, twitter, latitude-longitude, twitter-streaming-api

I am having problem in passing longitude and latitude format of Pakistan in [Twitter Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public). This API provides some sample [examples](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#locations) of passing longitude and latitude of some cities. The location for San Fransisco in the API location example is given below and it works very well in my program.

> -122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8

But I am trying to use the following location to get tweets from Pakistan but the server rejects this location.

> 71.69,32.01,70.69,33.01

Kindly help me which 4 values separated by commas I should pass that will allow me to get tweets from Pakistan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Each bounding box should be specified as a pair of longitude and
>   latitude pairs, **with the southwest corner of the bounding box coming
>   first.**

Your co-ordinates of `71.69,32.01,70.69,33.01` give this (which only seems to be a small part of Pakistan, might want to have a larger box):

[image]

So I *think* you box isn't being formed correctly because you're not giving the bottom left (South West) corner of it first. In order to give the box co-ordinates correctly you need to have them in the format `bottom-left-longitude, bottom-left-latitude, top-right-longitude, top-right-latitude`.

Try using `70.7,32.1,71.7,33.1` (I've rounded the figures) instead which will give you the same area you suggested originally:

[image]

In order to get the whole of Pakistan try using: `62.9,25.2,73.3,35.2` which give you the area:

[image]

I use [this website](http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html) in order to get the latitude/longitude values. *Note that the website gives you latitude, longitude but Twitter wants longitude, latitude. Remember to swap them around!*

Comment: I am also agreed on that point the location is just a single point from Pakistan not whole Pakistan is covering under the range of points. The coordinates that you have discussed i.e >70.7,32.1,71.7,33.1
is a valid location but it is also not covering the whole Pakistan. I am not understanding the format of passing location means there should be 4 values comma separated. Which value will be at 1st place and which at second and so on which value will be at 4th position after a comma. Help me

Comment: @OsamaJameelAhmad Okay I've edited my answer with the order (see in the middle, below the first picture, for this) and give some values at the end that cover most of Pakistan, if you want to literally cover the whole of Pakistan then due to it's shape you'll get some Tweets from Afganistan and India as well